# Why does my strategy doesnt show any data?

Tags: pine-script, back-testing

I am writing a simple strategy in pine script for backtesting in TradingView. Logic is simple. If today's close is less than 52 weeks low then purchase INR 10000 worth of stocks. My code looks as follows:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Darshan 52 week low", overlay=true)

// Get 52 week low value
weekly_lc = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", lowest(close,52), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// is close/open/high/low is less than 52 week low
if (close < weekly_lc)
    // if yes buy INR 10000 worth of stocks
    quantityToBuy = 10000/close
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, quantityToBuy)
```

This doesnt produce any data when ran against NSE:ITC stock. I am not sure why and there is no debugger available to see line by line behavior. I Tried to plot *weekly_lc* and it worked fine.

Update 1: I am putting my whole script here with exit condition.

```
    //@version=4
strategy("Darshan 52 week low", overlay=true)

// Get 52 week low value
weekly_lc = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", lowest(close,52), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

highAfterPurchase=0

// is close/open/high/low is less than 52 week low
if (close <= weekly_lc)
    // if yes buy INR 10000 worth of stocks
    quantityToBuy = 10000/close
    strategy.entry("darshan-long", strategy.long, quantityToBuy)

    // Set the purchase price as high
    highAfterPurchase = close

if (close > highAfterPurchase)
    highAfterPurchase = close

// is close price 15% lesser than high then exit 
closeHighDelta = highAfterPurchase - highAfterPurchase * 0.15
if (close < closeHighDelta)
    strategy.exit("exit", "darshan-long")
```

Strategy Tester screen looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you don't get any results because you don't have an **exit condition**? Do you see zero entries in the "_List of Trades_" tab?

Comment: @BarisYakut List of trades is zero. I put exit condition also with no effect.

Comment: Not really, I have prepared an answer for your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you look closely, you have one trade indeed. Entry condition has been met on 2000-04-24 with a price of 12.80. Exit condition is still *Open*, which means that your exit condition has not been met yet and you are still long.

I will try to show you what's going on with your strategy by showing you how to debug.

First, let's convert your strategy into an indicator. I would always start with an indicator and convert it to a strategy later when I'm satisfied with it.

To show if we have a BUY signal or SELL signal, we will use the `plotshape()` function and some additional variables.

```
//@version=4
study("Darshan 52 week low", overlay=true)

var isLong = false      // Flag to see if we are currently long
var isShort = false     // Flag to see if we are currently short

var highAfterPurchase = 0.0

// Get 52 week low value
weekly_lc = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", lowest(close,52), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

buySignal = not isLong and (close < weekly_lc)  // Buy only if not already long

highAfterPurchase := iff(buySignal, close, nz(highAfterPurchase[1]))    // If we are already long, update highAfterPurchase with the current close
                                                                        // else, keep the old value
// is close price 15% lesser than high then exit 
closeHighDelta = highAfterPurchase - (highAfterPurchase * 0.15)

sellSignal = not isShort and (close < closeHighDelta)   // Sell only if not alread short

if (buySignal)  // Reset signals
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal) // Reset signals
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

plotshape(series=buySignal, text="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)
```

Now, to debug this, we will create another indicator with the only difference being, `overlay=false` and different `plot`s. Here we want to plot signals that we are interested in. Signals that we want to see their values.

```
//@version=4
study("Darshan 52 week low Debug", overlay=false)

var isLong = false      // Flag to see if we are currently long
var isShort = false     // Flag to see if we are currently short

var highAfterPurchase = 0.0

// Get 52 week low value
weekly_lc = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", lowest(close,52), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

buySignal = not isLong and (close < weekly_lc)  // Buy only if not already long

highAfterPurchase := iff(buySignal, close, nz(highAfterPurchase[1]))    // If we are already long, update highAfterPurchase with the current close
                                                                        // else, keep the old value
// is close price 15% lesser than high then exit 
closeHighDelta = highAfterPurchase - (highAfterPurchase * 0.15)

sellSignal = not isShort and (close < closeHighDelta)   // Sell only if not alread short

if (buySignal)  // Reset signals
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal) // Reset signals
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

plot(series=close, title="close", color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(series=weekly_lc, title="weekly_lc", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(series=highAfterPurchase, title="highAfterPurchase", color=color.orange, linewidth=2)
plot(series=closeHighDelta, title="closeHighDelta", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Now, your *Buy Condition* is, when the green line (close) goes below the blue line (weekly_lc) and your *Sell Condition* is when the green line (close) goes below the red line (closeHighDelta).

If you look at the plots (you can make some of them invisible from the settings if you cannot see clearly), your buy condition only happens once and your sell condition never becomes `TRUE`. So, you are always ***LONG***.

Here is the modified strategy:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Darshan 52 week low", overlay=true)

// Time inputs that the strategy is going to apply on
FromMonth = input(defval = 01, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 01, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2018, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 08, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 31, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 2019, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)

// Time frame calculations
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"

var isLong = false      // Flag to see if we are currently long
var isShort = false     // Flag to see if we are currently short

var highAfterPurchase = 0.0

// Get 52 week low value
weekly_lc = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", lowest(close,52), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

buySignal = not isLong and (close < weekly_lc)  // Buy only if not already long

highAfterPurchase := iff(buySignal, close, nz(highAfterPurchase[1]))    // If we are already long, update highAfterPurchase with the current close
                                                                        // else, keep the old value
// is close price 15% lesser than high then exit 
closeHighDelta = highAfterPurchase - (highAfterPurchase * 0.15)

sellSignal = not isShort and (close < closeHighDelta)   // Sell only if not alread short

if (buySignal)  // Reset signals
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal) // Reset signals
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

strategy.entry(id="darshan-long", long=strategy.long, when=buySignal and window())
strategy.close(id="darshan-long", when=sellSignal and window())
```

As a side note, you should use the `:=` operator when you want to re-assign values to variables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your modified strategy and I didnt get one trade which I was getting. I changed the sell criteria from 15% to 1%.

Comment: Which timeframe are you using?

Comment: I havent specified any time frame. To be honest, I dont know how to specify timeframe. I removed my code and pasted your code.

As a part of my research, I found a stock which should generate sell signal immidiately. Stock name is IRB Infrastructure. But both our strategies fail to give exit signal.

Comment: Look at my first screenshot. There is an **M** next to the symbol (ITC) at the very top left. That indicates the timeframe of the chart is _Monthly_. Or you can look at the top left line of the chart where you see open, close, low, high values of the bars. ITC- **1M** - NSE. What do you see there?

Comment: I had W. I changed it to M and I got the one long trade. I used the same config and your strategy code for IRB which should generate exit immidiately. I am not sure where both of our logics are gong wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please have a look at the last line of the strategy script. I used `strategy.close()` and you get exit order also now.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for help. My strategy doesnt give me data what i am looking for. Can I run my strategy lets say starting from 1 Jan 2010 till now. I believe that will be more useful. Currently I enter sometime in 2005 and stay long which is not a bad sign but want to see the result in close quarters.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have a look at the new strategy script. At the very beginning there is a part to get some kind of time window from the user. Right after that, there is time frame calculations. `window()` is your flag that you should check before placing an order to see if order takes place in the desired time window. I have added that check in the `when` condition of the `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.close()`. You can change these time window values from the strategy settings or simply change the default values within the code.